# how to rummage through github code

Tags: git, github

I was wondering if anyone had any tricks for searching through github code. Here is the scenario I am talking about.

1. Looking through github project and I find the block of code I am looking for (for whatever reason)
2. That code calls some function (which may call another (which may call another...))

If I want to trace where all these calls go I usually just open a new tab and search the repo for the function name which brings up a lot of files that call it which I have to sift through until I come upon the definition of it...

Is there any feature of github, or just any efficient method of working to trace where a function call like this might go?

Comment: Since GitHub doesn't actually compile your code in any way, I doubt there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the source code comes from github (or some very different origin) is not relevant to your question: you get the source code from github (e.g. using `git clone`) and you work on the local copy on your computer. You'll work likewise with source code coming from something else that github.

<sup>(you'll better work on a *local* copy on your computer, because code navigation requires computing power, and you have more computing power locally than on github servers which are shared by thousands of users)</sup>

Then (once you have all the source code on your own computer) your question is a matter of understanding source code and navigating in it.

There are lots of software tools to help on that (starting from simple but effective tools like `grep` or [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/)... to [ctags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctags) and much more complex tools like [static source code analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) tools). You want to do *source code navigation* and you'll find [tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Code_navigation_tools) for that. Running the program on test cases in a debugger step by step also helps understanding it. And once you begin to study the source code, you can also ask the developer's community.

Of course, understanding large source code base (above a million lines of code) requires a lot of effort (years of work).

Answer (score 0):

There are two Chrome extensions that might help a bit:

Octotree: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/octotree/bkhaagjahfmjljalopjnoealnfndnagc

CodeNav:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/codenav-github-code-navig/nbgghbhaanommbapokejnmfdlddoacff

Neither is going to provide you with IDE-like code navigation, but they are helpful for perusing GitHub projects.